# How to process a string as a file to contruct a ZipFile object?

Tags: python, mysql, docx, python-zipfile

I am currently pulling data from a database with blobs. I retrieve the blob from the database, but I need to parse the text. the ZipFile class takes in files not strings, so what would be a good way to solve this?

```
import zipfile

data= request.files["file"].read() #this is just binary data
zipfile.ZipFile(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

use io.BytesIO or io.StringIO
essentially u just need file-like interface